# What does it mean "Haman only arose to serve as a rememberance"?

Tags: purim, haman

In the [Midrash Eicha Rabbah 3:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Eikhah_Rabbah.3.23?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%A8%D6%B7%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%99%20%D7%A0%D6%B8%D7%AA%D6%B8%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D6%B8%D7%9E%D6%B7%D7%A8%20%D7%9C%D6%B9%D7%90%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%90%20%D7%94%D6%B8%D7%9E%D6%B8%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D6%B6%D7%9C%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%90%20%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%96%D6%B5%D7%9B%D6%B6%D7%A8%20%D7%99%D6%B4%D7%A9%D7%82%D6%B0%D7%A8%D6%B8%D7%90%D6%B5%D7%9C) it says:

רַבִּי נָתָן אָמַר לֹא בָּא הָמָן אֶלָּא לְזֵכֶר יִשְׂרָאֵל

What does this mean? What was Haman serving as a remembrance for?

Comment: See also: https://www.sefaria.org/Mekhilta_DeRabbi_Yishmael%2C_Tractate_Amalek.2.44?lang=bi

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the [Yefeh Anaf on the Midrash (ad loc.)](https://www.sefaria.org/Yefeh_Anaf_on_Eichah_Rabbah.3.23.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%A8%D6%B7%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%99%20%D7%A0%D6%B8%D7%AA%D6%B8%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D6%B8%D7%9E%D6%B7%D7%A8%20%D7%9C%D6%B9%D7%90%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%90%20%D7%94%D6%B8%D7%9E%D6%B8%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D6%B6%D7%9C%D6%BC%D6%B8%D7%90%20%D7%9C%D6%B0%D7%96%D6%B5%D7%9B%D6%B6%D7%A8%20%D7%99%D6%B4%D7%A9%D7%82%D6%B0%D7%A8%D6%B8%D7%90%D6%B5%D7%9C). He seems to explain that this refers to the fact that we need to remember that through him,, we continue to preserve the memory of Amalek and its actions, as well as the requirement to destroy Amalek.

> לא בא המן אלא לזכר ישראל. פי' כדי שעל ידו יזכר לדורות גם מחיית עמלק שימי הפורים לא יעברו ולא תעבור גם מחיית עמלק וע"ע במכילתא שם: